# Anyone using mongoengine with Django auth

Tags: django, authentication, mongodb, mongoengine

I am quite new to both django and mongoengine. Is there any project I can refer to see basic implementation of user authentication and authorization.

Comment: This has some pieces of code:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492775/mongoengine-user-authentication-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mongokit

http://groups.google.com/group/mongokit/browse_thread/thread/c939c126c7b58106