# MongoEngine User authentication (django)

Tags: python, django, authentication, mongoengine

I am trying to use MongoEngine in a django project I am writing. I am having difficulty getting (or understanding how) the authentication backend works.

The user object as far as I can tell is not stored in the request.

I have it working but I am not sure if I am doing it in the right/safe way. If someone could look at my code I would be much appreciated.

```
def login(request):
    user = authenticate(request.POST['username'],request.POST['password'])
    if user is not None:
        request.session['user'] = user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponse(user)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('login failed')

def new_page(request):
    try:
        user = request.session['user']
        if user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponse('welcome')
    except:
        return HttpResponse('need be logged in')
```

in my settings.py I have added at the top of the file:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'

import mongoengine
mongoengine.connect('project')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if you are seeing any issues because you make no mention of any but I use mongoengine for my auth backend and this is how I would handle it:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, User
from mongoengine.queryset import DoesNotExist

def login_view(request):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
        if user.check_password(request.POST['password']):
            user.backend = 'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend'
            login(request, user)
            request.session.set_expiry(60 * 60 * 1) # 1 hour timeout
            return HttpResponse(user)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('login failed')
    except DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse('user does not exist')
    except Exception
        return HttpResponse('unknown error')
```

You say the user is not stored in the request...if you mean it is not available in templates, you need to add the auth template context processor in your settings (in addition to the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting you have set already):

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    ...
)
```

To make the user attached to subsequent requests after login, set the `AuthenticationMiddleware`  and the user will be an attribute of the `request` in all your views:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I have it working exactly how it should now, one note is you should not call the view `login` as it clashed with the actual login function.

Comment: correct, i was copying your example. what I wrote was to show the pattern

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! It might make sense though to import **User** from **mongoengine.django.auth** (the "regular" User must be imported from **django.contrib.auth.models**, not **django.contrib.auth**)

Comment: Could you pls provide full example?

Comment: @Burak - that is the full example.  where are you stuck?

Comment: I stucked at urls.py, view.py and templates

Comment: @MattoTodd, I am new to Django with mongodb, How to create user collection in mongodb with django.Plase help

Comment: Hey there matto,  I am stuck at the authentication: It goes straight to Exception: saying "unknown error"... What could be the problem i have the settings.py set according what you have mentioned...

Comment: @Sunil - that means its some other exception being thrown - use `except Exception, e:` and you will have access to the actual exception in the exception block to see what the issue is. Basically you should log what `e` is or print it out