# mongoengine and django auth, login

Tags: django, authentication, mongoengine

I am trying to implement login functionality using mongoengine and django.

I have included 'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth' in INSTALLED_APPS

Following are my settings.py from mongoengine site.

```
MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT = 'mongoengine.django.auth.User'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'
SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)
```

This is from models.py

```
class UserInfo(User,DynamicDocument):
    address = EmbeddedDocumentField(Address)
    dob = DateTimeField(required = True)
    sex = StringField(max_length = 1, choices = SEX)
    primary_number = LongField(required = True)
```

And following is from views.py

```
def LoginOrCreateUser(request):

    formAuth = AuthenticationForm(data=(request.POST or None))
    if(request.method=='POST'):
              if(formAuth.is_valid()):
                            if(formAuth.clean_email()):
                                    if(formAuth.clean_password()):
                                            formAuth.save(True)                
                                            user=authenticate(username=formAuth.cleaned_data['username'],password = formAuth.cleaned_data['password1'])
                                            login(request,user)                
                                            return HttpResponse('New User Success')
```

> **This code gives me error <obj_id "user"> is NOT JSON serializable.**
>   The error is raised for login, so I guess here login API is provided by django but the user we are providing to it is the value got from authenticate which is mongoengine's provided api.

I looked into the auth.py of django and mongoengine. So, we don't have login API in mongoengine. And the authenticate of django returns the user instance, while authenticate of mongoengine returns a string i.e. username.

Any suggestions here or mistakes I am making in the implementation here.

Answer (score 1):

1st question, are you trying to customize the User object? Or you want to use default Django User model? I ask because you should set MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT and AUTH_USER_MODEL if you do want to make a custom model.

I will show you how I'm authenticating using mongoengine x Django:

**On settings.py**

```
connect('localhost')
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend'
)
SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
```

**On views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponse

def jsonResponse(responseDict):
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(responseDict), mimetype='application/json')

def createSession(request):
    if not request.is_ajax():
        return jsonResponse({'error':True})  

    if not request.session.exists(request.session.session_key):
        request.session.create() 

    data = extractDataFromPost(request)
    email = data["email"]
    password = data["password"]

    try: 
        user = User.objects.get(username=email)
        if user.check_password(password):
            user.backend = 'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend'
            user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            request.session.set_expiry(3600000) # 1 hour timeout
            return jsonResponse(serializeUser(user)) 
        else:
            result = {'error':True, 'message':'Invalid credentials'}
            return jsonResponse(result) 
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        result = {'error':True, 'message':'Invalid credentials'}
        return jsonResponse(result) 


def serializeUser(user):
    return simplejson.dumps({'email': user.email, 'username': user.username, 'id': str(user.id), 'firstName': user.first_name, 'lastName': user.last_name})
```

After reading lots of stuff I could make it work this way following [MongoEngine User authentication (django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492775/mongoengine-user-authentication-django).

I'm not setting anything on models.py since I use the default Django user model.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

André I just tried you're example but it gives me

> ```
> NameError at /game/
> global name 'jsonResponse' is not defined
> ```

If I import jsonResponse like

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,JsonResponse
```

then gives me

> ImportError at /game/ cannot import name JsonResponse

I just only want to manage simple user auth with my mongoengine backend.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for that @BugFixer, I've implemented this jsonResponse method. Will edit my answer to include it. Regards, AT

Comment: I can't make it run, May you could give me a hand in my open question about mongoengine/django user auth, if you could give me a hand I will appreciate that ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861077/django-auth-with-mongoengine-db