# User attribute not attached to request object in subsequent requests in mongoengine auth

Tags: django, mongoengine, django-authentication

I've tried to use the link below for the solution for login, but when I do /login it will initially have the user attribute added to the request. When I make subsequent calls after that the user attribute isn't persisted on the request object.

[MongoEngine User authentication (django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492775/mongoengine-user-authentication-django)

In my settings.py I do import the AuthenticationMiddleware so it should persist the user attribute but its not.

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from mongoengine.django.auth import User
from mongoengine.queryset import DoesNotExist
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import json

def login_view(request):
        user = User.objects.get(username='john')
        user.backend = 'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend'
        login(request, user)
        request.session.set_expiry(60 * 60 * 1) # 1 hour timeout
        if(request.user.is_authenticated()):
            return HttpResponse(request.user.username)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Not Authenticated!')


def do_something(request):
     return HttpResponse(request.user.username)
```

Here is my settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for questiveAuth project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '%skvtelk+53alr^y8lr4z5d1+4_!_kgmy8%w0ip_%e&^ug$kas'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

LOGIN_URL = '/loginredirect/'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth',
    'rest_framework'
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'
MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT = 'mongoengine.django.auth.User'

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'mongoengine.django.sessions.BSONSerializer'




MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'questiveAuth.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'questiveAuth.wsgi.application'

from mongoengine import *

connect('questAuth')

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
    }
}

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',  
)


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to tell Django to use the mongoengine backend instead.

In your settings.py file add the following:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
)
```

Tested with your code and it works as intended.